# Initializing Texture2DArray

Tags: c++, directx, textures

I'm trying to create and initialize a 2D texture array in the following way:

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc{};
desc.ArraySize = 10; // there should be 10 textures
desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS;
desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
desc.Width = 256;
desc.Height = 1;
desc.MipLevels = 1;
desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA subresourceData{};
subresourceData.pSysMem = data.data(); // data is a vector of 2560 elements of type XMVECTOR
subresourceData.SysMemPitch = 256 * sizeof(XMVECTOR);
subresourceData.SysMemSlicePitch = 256 * sizeof(XMVECTOR);

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> m_texture = nullptr;

m_device->CreateTexture2D(&desc, &subresourceData, &m_texture);
```

The problem is I'm getting an error `Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` on calling `CreateTexture2D` and `m_texture` in `NULL`. When I did not pass initialization data the problem did not occur:

```
m_device->CreateTexture2D(&desc, nullptr, &m_texture);
```

How can I initialize a texture array?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to show how you define `m_texture`

Comment: @MatG Right, I've included it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: for texture array you have to pass an array of `D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA` in `CreateTexture2D` function.